# Decode the string and store the values in mysql database using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

```
$scope.updatedTable = function() {
    var updatedTable = JSON.stringify($scope.TableDetails);

    $http.post('controllers/updateTable.php',{'data':updatedTable})
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                $log.error(err);
            });
}
```

When the above function is fired , JSON.stringify converts the array of objects to a string and stores it in updatedTable variable .

**Before converting it to a string :**

```
$scope.TableDetails= [
        {  
           name:'Sachin',
           country:'India'
        },
        {  
           name:'Ponting',
           country:'Australia'
        },
        {  
           name:'AB De villears',
           country:'South Africa'
        },
        {  
           name:'Sangakara',
           country:'Sri Lanka'
        },
        {  
           name:'McCullum',
           country:'New Zealand'
        }
];
```

**After Converting it to a string**

[{name:'Sachin',country:'India'},{name:'Ponting',country:'Australia'},{name:'AB de villears',country:'South Africa'},{name:'Sangakara',country:'Sri Lanka'},{name:'McCullum',country:'New Zealand'}]

**What I want to achieve :**

The above is the string which is being sent to the php file . In php file , I want to decode the above string and store it in a Table (MySQL Database). The table columns are NAME and COUNTRY .  Can anybody post the php code which takes care of inserting the values into mysql table ? Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: This is what I have done so far Alex .

Comment: <?php 

 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";
  $db = "database";

  $con = new mysqli($host , $user , $pass , $db);

Comment: After that , I should write the insert query . But I don't know how to decode the string

Comment: You have decoded json in $data variable. Check it, what is inside?

Comment: @danshi yeah . when I echo it , it prints nothing :(

Comment: Inspect what is in input request data? Try to decode with json_decode($json, true)  (assoc=True).

Comment: can somebody post the code ?

Comment: Not at all clear what you are even asking